# How to display an Image in HTML from javascript's JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json, image

I already retrieved data that will be needed from displaying two images in HTML, but my problem is i don't know how to plug the values from JSON data into  properly in order to be displayed as a picture. Here's my current progress:

[image]

Here's my snippet code:

```
<div class = "modal-body">
        <p>Original Image: <span id = "Orig_Image"></span></p>
        <img src = "Orig_Image" alt="Original Image" height="200" width="200">
        <p>RGB Image: <span id = "RGB_Image"></span></p>
        <img src = "RGB_Image" alt="RGB Image" height="200" width="200">
     </div>

<script>
function showDetails(button){
    var Report_ID = button.id;
    $.ajax({
    url: "Retrieve_Image.php",
    method: "GET",
    data: {"Report_ID": Report_ID},
    success: function(response){
        //alert(response);
        var Images = JSON.parse(response);
        $("#Orig_Image").text(Images.Original_Image_Directory);
        $("#RGB_Image").text(Images.RGB_Image_Directory);
        $("#myModalLabel").text(Images.Image_Name);
    }
});
}
</script>
```

**QUESTION**

> How can i pass the values I retrieved from JSON to img? If the solution I want is not possible? is there any other way I can display the images?

**UPDATE**

Here's the value that JSON returns from the file Retrieve_Image.php

> these are the following values that JSON returns.
>
> 1. Parameter is the Image name
> 2. Parameter is the file path and its image name for Original Image
> 3. Parameter is the file path and its image name for RGB Image

[image]

Comment: Is `Images` a json array? What src do the images have after the ajax call?

Comment: `$("#RGB_Image").parent().siblings('img').attr('src', Images.RGB_Image_Directory);`

Comment: You should return Image byte data into Base64 in json and then using <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />

Comment: @ImAtWar it's not array

Comment: @Jai i tried but still didn't work.. $("#RGB_Image").parent().siblings('img')attr('src',Images.RGB_Image_Directory);

Comment: @Denzell can you add the object in your post, you got in your response?

Comment: @Jai I already included the response from JSON, I updated my post :D you can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class = "modal-body">
        <p>Original Image: <span ></span></p>
        <img src = "Orig_Image" id="Orig_Image" alt="Original Image" height="200" width="200">
        <p>RGB Image: <span ></span></p>
        <img src = "RGB_Image" id="RGB_Image" alt="RGB Image" height="200" width="200">
     </div>

<script>
function showDetails(button){
    var Report_ID = button.id;
    $.ajax({
    url: "Retrieve_Image.php",
    method: "GET",
    data: {"Report_ID": Report_ID},
    success: function(response){
        //alert(response);
        var Images = JSON.parse(response);
        $("#Orig_Image").attr('src',Images.Original_Image_Directory);
        $("#RGB_Image").attr('src',Images.RGB_Image_Directory);
        $("#myModalLabel").text(Images.Image_Name);
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: same `id`s are invalid markup. Could create issues.

Comment: still didn't work , what's the difference between src and id in your code?

Comment: @Denzell in an `<img` tag the "src" attribute is the one which should contain the URL to the image. That's the bit you need to populate with your data. That is what this example is doing. The problem might come if what's in your JSON is not a valid URL (either relative or absolute), or is not the correct URL to the image file. If you still have an issue might be sensible if you edit the question to show us your JSON data. Also, when running this code, watch your browser's Network tools - you should see HTTP requests to fetch the images going out, and see if they succeed

Comment: Suresh, your code is fine but you should be explaining what you are changing, and why, since it may not be obvious to everyone. Code without explanation doesn't help anyone to learn.

Comment: @ADyson yes i know, but how do i plus the values i retrieve from JSON into the <img src> ? i tried suresh's code but still didn't work. I already tried to print the values in text form and no problem. the only problem i want to fix is to plug it in the src of img in order to display it as an image.

Comment: Suresh's code _is_ putting the values into the "src" property...assuming that a) the JSON structure is correct and b) your ajax call suceeded. If both of those worked, then you still won't see an image unless c) what you placed into the "src" is a valid URL. If you show us the JSON coming back from your PHP page then we can help to confirm whether that's the case. You can also use your browser's Developer Tools to check all 3 of the things I've just mentioned.

Comment: I already updated my thread and included the output of JSON from my PHP script